# Swift Modally Segue

Tags: swift, interface-builder, segue

Using the storyboard interface I setup a segue from my HomeViewcontroller to my SettingsViewController with ' Present modally' and presentation 'form sheet'. How can I access the existing HomeViewController instance that is sitting behind the SettingsViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is the presented view controller's `presentingViewController`.

If not, use the standard protocol-and-delegate pattern to give the SettingsViewController a communications path back to the HomeViewController. It's more work to configure, but it's worth mastering.